# Date and time format for UK in a custom post type

Tags: date, date-time

I display the date format of my custom post type like: `jS M Y`

which display: `24th May 2016`

It's great, however, I would like to add the time, keeping this format.

Is there any format type for this ? It seems I can find only US format !

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want 24 hour time, you want something like `jS M Y H:i:s`.

You can check wordpresses own [Formatting Date and Time](https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time) reference for further details.